# Conflicting transaction in memory pool

Tags: client

A conflicting transaction has been detected in our memory pool. The transaction hash displayed below may change.

https://blockchain.info/tx/9475b7f376ad9e843149c91cf207573f5150a739596432b65962f9ff4fd3ab0b

I don't know what to do; I cant withdraw that transaction!!!!!!

Comment: This is a service related problem, [you should open a ticket with your wallet provider](https://blockchain.info/support-desk).

Comment: This is not service related problem. This is transaction malleability

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, and what would constitute a complete answer. Please be more specific in the description of your topic and your question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the transaction was confirmed with a different txid here:
https://blockchain.info/tx/d69fc595f15bb4680025f794ede1c863551c485fab478ea2dcc0a1da36d4e6fd?show_adv=true

Comment: i should receive 2 68 dollars worth of bitcoins from same address i received them i used my first 68 dollars second told me i cant spend !!!!

Comment: I assume that your wallet address is 1MAqYeQutjyLMoF9UP95K1vjcgp72xLPsp ? From the confirmed transaction I posted above, you can see that the payment of 0.286 BTC (~68 USD) was send to 13qHw8q3s8k6DZ7MUGX6cR68q3agGHEa29 and the rest (1.83 BTC) was send back to your address 1MAqYeQutjyLMoF9UP95K1vjcgp72xLPsp and is still sitting there. So as long as you have the private key for that address everything is still fine! What bitcoin wallet are you using?

Comment: my bitcoin wallet is 13qHw8q3s8k6DZ7MUGX6cR68q3agGHEa29  using blockchain and i should receive 2 0.286

Comment: You must contact the person/company that should have send you 2x68 dollars in bitcoins. They made two transactions, but both of which try to use "the same bitcoins" to send to you. Since that is a double spend, only one of those transactions are in the Blockchain. The other one will never become spendable.

Comment: but in my account it says my final balance is 67 dollars right now

Comment: Using blockchain.info's own analizer you can see that your current balance is 0 BTC: https://blockchain.info/address/13qHw8q3s8k6DZ7MUGX6cR68q3agGHEa29 If the blockchain.info wallet shows you differently, then it is a mixup because of the double-spend attempt (which should not happen, since their own software confirms that the balance in fact is 0 btc and the pending transaction is a double spend)