# How do I resolve an accidental double spend?

Tags: transactions

I made a double payment to the same address mistakenly since my internet was a bit slow, and one payment has 8 confirmations. The recipient says he hasn't received it. I got this message from the transaction:

> A conflicting transaction has been detected in our memory pool. The transaction hash displayed below may change.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything. Since the transactions conflict, the second one will never confirm.

Answer (score 1):

A double spend is not possible. A double spend *attempt*, yes. You might try and (accidentally or intentionally) broadcast two different transactions that spend the same bitcoins. But only one will eventually get included in a block.

If you say one payment has 8 confirmations, then that's the one that became final ('set in stone') and the other will never happen.

Comment: a double spent **is** possible. with altering the mainchain from some past block

Comment: yes, but it is highly unlikely that someone has right now the ability to mine 8 blocks before there are any new blocks.

Comment: @amaclin That's extremely unlikely, but even if someone pulls it off, the earlier transaction no longer exists. So eventually, that first spend never took place.

Answer (score 0):

> The recipient says he hasn't received it.

Show him this transaction on any blockexplorer site

E.g. on blockchain.info

See also [Conflicting transaction in memory pool](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40716/conflicting-transaction-in-memory-pool)